# Strange Integrate behavior (a bug!)

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis, bugs

The following two calculations should give the same result. After all, integration is a linear operation.

[image]

---

I have pasted the code below in case you want to play with it.

```
Integrate[Integrate[v[x], x] - 
     Integrate[Integrate[v[x], x] * u'[x], x]/u[x], x]

Integrate[Integrate[v[x], x], x] - 
   Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[v[x], x] * u'[x], x]/u[x], x]
```

Comment: if i plug in example functions for v,u I get the same result (not zero)

Comment: Should I tag this question as "bug"?

Comment: @Hector No, every integration is defined up to an additive constant. Therefore answer is defined up to a nontrivial function.

Comment: @ybeltukov: Nice point. I expanded the first integral by hand keeping track of the constants of integration. I got that the arbitrary function is a linear combination of `1`, `x`, and `Integrate[1/u[x],x]`. Thus, it cannot cover every possible `u` and `v` that we throw to it.

Comment: @Hector Indeed. Most likely *Mathematica* think that `Integrate[v[x], x]` is a constant (i.e. bug).

Comment: Simpler example illustrating @ybeltukov's comment: `Integrate[Integrate[Integrate[v[x], x] * Derivative[1][u][x], x] - Integrate[v[x], x] * Integrate[Derivative[1][u][x], x], x]` evaluates to zero.  Note that it does not evaluate to zero if the outside `Integrate` is removed.